# Angular CDK context menu - populate menus based on selected row

Tags: javascript, dynamic, contextmenu, angular-cdk, angular16

I have an Angular CDK context menu for my application
But i need to populate the menus based on the selected row item.
After user selects a row item based on it data need to populate respective menus for it
how can that be done ?
in ts

```
import {CdkContextMenuTrigger, CdkMenuItem, CdkMenu} from '@angular/cdk/menu';
```

in html

```
<div [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="context_menu">Hi click me</div>

<ng-template #context_menu>
    <div class="example-menu" cdkMenu>
      <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Cut</button>
      <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Copy</button>
      <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Link</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```